# Excel - Merging Spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to merge two spreadsheets together through common data in the A column and make the two aligned. The first spreadsheet has more information in the A column then the second spreadsheet so i cant just sort them lined up from A - Z is there an way I can do this.
Here is an example of the information i have:
[Question Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkLNo.png)

Comment: I would create a database with 2 tables.  Table 1 would have all field names even if they were blank. (some like this) Then update from table1 where table1.productname=table2.productname.  Then export to CSV, open in excel, and then use Text to Columns in excel using the comma delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Use **vlookup**.

e.g.:

To get "box barcode" from table2:
`=VLOOKUP(<NAME>,<SPREADSHEET2_TABLE>,2)`

To get "product barcode" from table2:
`=VLOOKUP(<NAME>,<SPREADSHEET2_TABLE>,3)`

This is just a start, you can further enhance the formulae to handle NA (when the vlookup cannot find a value in table2, because table1 has more values).